# filling spinners from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, spinner

i am trying to fill all my spinners in the my app from external DB.
The problem is that my app crushes in that line of the code:

```
cat_sp_add=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.categories_add_new_product);
```

im using as you can see in the code the method runOnUiThread but still it cruses. here is the code. somebody can please tell me what im doing wrong?

```
package com.example.zygy1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Load_lists extends Activity implements Runnable {

final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
final String TAG_CITIES = "cities";
final String TAG_CATEGORIES = "categories";
final String TAG_NAME = "name";

final String url_load_lists = "http://zygy.co.il/lib/android_connect/load_lists.php";
boolean error=false;

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<String> CategoriesList;
ArrayList<String> CitiesList;
JSONArray categories = null;
JSONArray cities = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
static Spinner cities_sp_add;
static  Spinner cities_sp_signUp;
static  Spinner cat_sp_add;
static  Spinner cat_sp_search;


@Override
public void run() {   

runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

     public void run(){
            ArrayList<Product> productList_final=new ArrayList<Product>();
            cat_sp_add=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.categories_add_new_product);
             cat_sp_search=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.categories_search);
                cities_sp_add=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cities_add_new_product);
                cities_sp_signUp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cities_signUp);
            CategoriesList = new ArrayList<String>();
            CitiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
            // Building Parameters
       List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_CITIES,"true"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_CATEGORIES,"true"));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_load_lists, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
           Log.d("Add new product ", json.toString());
 // getting lists from database
            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    categories=json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIES);
                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
                        String cat_name = new String();
                        cat_name=c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        CategoriesList.add(cat_name);
                    }
                    cities=json.getJSONArray(TAG_CITIES);
                    for (int i = 0; i < cities.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = cities.getJSONObject(i);
                        String city_name = new String();
                        city_name=c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        CitiesList.add(city_name);
                    }
                }
                 else {
                    // no match found
                   error=true;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
// set lists in all application
        if(!error){
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.spinner_text,CategoriesList);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text);
            cat_sp_add.setAdapter(adapter);
  //          cat_sp_search.setAdapter(adapter);

           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
           R.layout.spinner_text,CitiesList);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text);
           cities_sp_add.setAdapter(adapter);
  //         cities_sp_signUp.setAdapter(adapter);

           }
            else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error in uploading lists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }        
     }});
     }

}
```

The main class that activate the thread:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Load_lists load=new Load_lists();
    Thread load_lists=new Thread(load);
    load_lists.start();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
    bt_log_in=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_log_in);
    bt_sign_up=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sign_up);
    ....contine }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to declear your variables out of the thread within the onCreate.

Make sure that you make them final, then you can access it within the Thread.

Reason is, that the Layout is not loaded when you start your Thread. You may also want to try using setContentView() BEFORE you start your Thread.

Comment: it does not recognize the variables  if i declare them in oncreate. also i dont use it as activity so i dont know if the oncreate will run

Comment: public class Load_lists extends Activity implements Runnable { }

means it's an Activity. IT does mean it has an onCreate.

Oh, and by the way. You can also assign your views to your runnable. 


void Foo(String str) {
    class YourRunnableTask implements Runnable {
        String str;
        YourRunnableTask (String s) { str = s; }
        public void run() {
            someFunc(str);
        }
    }
    Thread t = new Thread(new YourRunnableTask (str));
    t.start();
}

Comment: ok got it. but still when you declare the variable in the on create it does not recognize the variable in the run function, so the soultion doesnt work